# Autopreenchimento de tabelas

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft

Trabalho no setor de capacitação na Secretaria de Fazenda. Estou montando um guia simples preenchimento para requerimento de capacitação das secretarias setoriais.

[![Imagem do formulário][1]][1]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é a seguinte:

A secretaria setorial seleciona numa lista suspensa em "Curso desejado" o treinamento que deseja realizar e o "objetivos gerais do treinamento" seria automaticamente preenchido de acordo com a seleção feita a cima. É como se fosse uma um preenchimento Y baseado na escolha X.

Desculpe se for uma dúvida boba, mas estou realmente quebrando galho nessa área de Dados.

****Estou utilizando o MICROSOFT WORD 2010**

Comment: E você já tem todas essas informações cadastradas em uma base de dados?

Comment: Oi Reginaldo,  Já tenho sim... através de qual ferramenta eu poderia fazer esse procedimento acima? Se puder me ajudar no nome eu ja consigo buscar no google.. por toda vez que busco sobre dados acabo sendo jogado da dúvidas do excel.

Comment: E o requerente irá acessar essa lista de cursos no site da Fazenda. Certo?

Comment: Exato, a ideia é ter as opções dos curso na lista suspensa e no momento da seleção apareça a descrição em "objetivos gerais do treinamento"

Comment: E esse site esta escrito em que linguagem? Você conhece basicamente a linguagem desse site? O banco de dados que ele acessa é o mesmo onde estão esse cadastro sobre os cursos?

Comment: Oi Reginaldo, este arquivo esta numa tabela no MS Word 2010.. vou editar a imagem do posto para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Alguma ideia? Minha única preocupação é o documento ser de facil preenchimento.. Por que temos grandes barreiras tecnológicas